# how to get the data of groupBy and the count in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by

How to get the count of `groupBy` and also the data?

I've tried this one but it only returns the count, without the data.

```
$data = Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->select('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->groupBy('status')
                ->get();
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->selectRaw('id, status, count(*) AS count')
                ->groupBy('status')
                ->get();
```

Haven't tested. It will be something like this. This will return an array with id, status and count. If it doesnt work let me know.

but if you including `id` which is unique and does not make sense in a groupby this way, your mysql should be enabled to do so, otherwise it will throw `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` error laravel. It can handled by changing the mode. but I would recommend removing the order by id.

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // Behave like MySQL 5.6
        'strict' => false,

        // Behave like MySQL 5.7
        'strict' => true,
    ]
]
```

Comment: Got an error `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 ... isn't in GROUP BY`

Comment: ya, i just updated the answer. just realised that id has been used in the query

Comment: Mine was set to `true`.

Comment: I can get the `id` now, but how can I get all the data? like `select * from tablename`

Comment: instead of * use all column names as you are using count. like selectRaw('id, status, another_filed, another,count(*) AS count')

Comment: Okay, thanks.. is there performance changes after I change the `strict` to `false`?

Comment: no. just the thing is that you are saying mysql not to be so strict and this is to let you use this not so cool to group id field to be included in the group by query